# convertTo Node/World Space

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I have a CCLayer in cocos2d, ono which I;m trying to place a CCSprite to fill the background. There are two instances of this CCLayer in my scene, for on of them, the background is displayed in the correct position with a little offsetting, but for the the other I can't get the layer to even display. I have a feeling this is down to not using the correct combination of self/self.parent/self.parent.parent and convertTo/Node/World/AR/Space.

This is my code which works for one instance of the layer:

```
CGPoint offsetPos = [self convertToWorldSpace:self.position];
if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)){
    bgSprite.position = ccp(offsetPos.x+60, offsetPos.y);
} else {
    bgSprite.position = ccp(offsetPos.x-65, offsetPos.y);
}
```

To try to see where this is tripping up for the other layer (determined by an `isThumbnail` property, I added some logging:

```
if(self.isThumbnail){
        NSLog(@"--: %.0f,%.0f", self.bgSprite.position.x, self.bgSprite.position.x);
        NSLog(@"A: %.0f,%.0f", [self.parent convertToWorldSpace:self.bgSprite.position].x, [self.parent convertToWorldSpace:self.bgSprite.position].y);
        NSLog(@"B: %.0f,%.0f", [self convertToWorldSpace:self.bgSprite.position].x, [self convertToWorldSpace:self.bgSprite.position].y);
        NSLog(@"C: %.0f,%.0f", [self.parent convertToNodeSpace:self.bgSprite.position].x, [self.parent convertToNodeSpace:self.bgSprite.position].y);
        NSLog(@"D: %.0f,%.0f", [self convertToNodeSpace:self.bgSprite.position].x, [self convertToNodeSpace:self.bgSprite.position].y);
        NSLog(@"E: %.0f,%.0f", [self.parent convertToWorldSpaceAR:self.bgSprite.position].x, [self.parent convertToWorldSpaceAR:self.bgSprite.position].y);
        NSLog(@"F: %.0f,%.0f", [self convertToWorldSpaceAR:self.bgSprite.position].x, [self convertToWorldSpaceAR:self.bgSprite.position].y);

        NSLog(@"--: %.0f,%.0f", self.position.x, self.position.x);
        NSLog(@"G: %.0f,%.0f", [self.parent convertToWorldSpace:self.position].x, [self.parent convertToWorldSpace:self.position].y);
        NSLog(@"H: %.0f,%.0f", [self convertToWorldSpace:self.position].x, [self convertToWorldSpace:self.position].y);
        NSLog(@"I: %.0f,%.0f", [self.parent convertToNodeSpace:self.position].x, [self.parent convertToNodeSpace:self.position].y);
        NSLog(@"J: %.0f,%.0f", [self convertToNodeSpace:self.position].x, [self convertToNodeSpace:self.position].y);
        NSLog(@"K: %.0f,%.0f", [self.parent convertToWorldSpaceAR:self.position].x, [self.parent convertToWorldSpaceAR:self.position].y);
        NSLog(@"L: %.0f,%.0f", [self convertToWorldSpaceAR:self.position].x, [self convertToWorldSpaceAR:self.position].y);

        NSLog(@"--: %.0f,%.0f", self.bgSprite.position.x, self.bgSprite.position.x);
        NSLog(@"M: %.0f,%.0f", [self.parent.parent convertToWorldSpace:self.bgSprite.position].x, [self.parent.parent convertToWorldSpace:self.bgSprite.position].y);
        NSLog(@"N: %.0f,%.0f", [self.parent.parent convertToNodeSpace:self.bgSprite.position].x, [self.parent.parent convertToNodeSpace:self.bgSprite.position].y);
        NSLog(@"O: %.0f,%.0f", [self.parent.parent convertToWorldSpaceAR:self.bgSprite.position].x, [self.parent.parent convertToWorldSpaceAR:self.bgSprite.position].y);
```

Resulting in:

```
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] --: -55,-55
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] A: -55,587
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] B: -45,1074
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] C: -55,487
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] D: -65,0
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] E: -55,587
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] F: -45,1074
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] --: 10,10
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] G: 10,537
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] H: 20,1024
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] I: 10,437
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] J: 0,-50
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] K: 10,537
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] L: 20,1024
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] --: -55,-55
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] M: -55,537
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] N: -55,537
ReadMeAStory[3853:c07] O: 309,954
```

Could someone explain which one is needed in this case, and perhaps how to know?

EDIT: The background sprite is added to the hierarchy with:

```
    UIImage *bgImage = [Utils backgroundWithName:currentScene.background];
    bgSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:bgImage.CGImage key:currentScene.background];
    bgSprite.contentSize = self.contentSize;
    [self updateBackground];
    [self addChild:bgSprite z:0];
```

The heirarchy looks like this (brackets show order in which elements are added)

```
-Scene
--Main layer (1) - background in correct position
--Other layers container (2)
---Other layer A (3)
----Background sprite (7)
---Other layer B (4)
----Background sprite (8)
---Other layer C (5)
----Background sprite (9)
---Other layer D (6)
----Background sprite (10)
```

Comment: It would help to see how the cclayer and ccsprite were added to the hierarchy. That affects which conversion method you need to use.

Comment: Thanks, I've added more detail.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, could you elabrorate a bit on why the order in which the layers are added matters please?

Comment: Not the order matters but the parent-child relationship. Why do you use so many layers?

Comment: I use the layers as the user can customize the content of them.